# how to avoid rebinding grid each time the control is initialized?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I've created a custom user control with a grid. I'd like to bind this grid once, and use it over and over again in my app. If I put the binding within the control, the data is retrieved as many times as I use the control. How do I bind it only once??

```
public ClientLookUp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        vw_clientsTableAdapter.Fill(dsclientlkup.vw_clients); //This occurs as many times as I have the user control, instead of just once.

    }
```

Comment: That is not a function, is the constructor (does not have a return type)

Answer (score 0):

Well anything you put in the constructor will be executed every time you construct the object!
What about providing an Initialize method that you can call whenever you need to reload the data??

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to use the same single grid in your control over and over, you could create a single, static grid, and have your ClientLookUp constructor add it to the right place—Panel, or whatever—whenever a new one is created.

Before you go do this road however, ask yourself if this is really what you want to do.  Having the same identical grid existing in many places may cause you problems down the road.  If you want to support in-grid editing, you'll find that changing one value changes the identical value in all your other grids..

**EDIT**

I tried getting the below code to work, but I'm not sure this approach will be possible.  It seems as though the minute you try to attach the same UI element into more than one place, it gets moved out of the last place you put it; it doesn't look like you can have the same grid being in more than one place at once.  This makes sense when you think about it.

Here's the code I tried.  Maybe it will be of some use to you.

```
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Controls.Add(myStaticGridView);
        myStaticGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    static DataGridView _staticGrid;
    public DataGridView myStaticGridView
    {
        get
        {
            if (_staticGrid != null)
                return _staticGrid;

            _staticGrid = new DataGridView();
            _staticGrid.Columns.Add("A", "A");
            _staticGrid.Columns.Add("B", "B");
            _staticGrid.Columns.Add("C", "C");

            _staticGrid.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "A";
            _staticGrid.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "B";
            _staticGrid.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "C";

            _staticGrid.DataSource = new[] {
                new { A = "someA", B = "someB", C = "someC"},
                new { A = "someA", B = "someB", C = "someC"},
                new { A = "someA", B = "someB", C = "someC"},
                new { A = "someA", B = "someB", C = "someC"},
            };

            return _staticGrid;
        }
    }
```

And then loading the control like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new UserControl1());
    }
```

Comment: It's not really a grid; it's a dropdown with a list of clients that I need to use on many pages of the application. It will never change, or be updated. I figured the best way would be to create a custom control and just drop it anywhere I need it. I had hoped to avoid binding each one separately.

Comment: Well the same principles apply.  If you're going to use this dropdown in many places, then by all means cache the **data** that they all use, but trying to cache the actual drop down and use **that** in many places will cause you more harm than good—assuming it's even possible

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the data only once, then load it either into a static variable or a separate class that is referenced by the control.